# Loading DLG file into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-formats, usgs

I downloaded hypsography (topo lines) in DLG (Digital Line Graph) format. The file came from [OGRIP](https://ogrip.oit.ohio.gov/ServicesData/GEOhioSpatialInformationPortal/OhioSpatialDataInfrastructureDownloads.aspx), although it originally came from USGS. According to Wikipedia, DLG files are

> topologically structured for use in mapping and geographic information system (GIS) applications.

However, when I try to load the .dlg file into QGIS, I get an error message:

> Invalid Data Source: C:/Users/.../cl303ohy.dlg is not a valid or recognized data source.

Searching for how to load a DLG file into QGIS doesn't yield any helpful results. Apparently 'dlg' is used in the python coding for creating or loading a plugin, so all the search results discuss plugins.

**How can I use a DLG file in QGIS?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DLG (Digital Line Graph) format is not a valid OGR data source (it can be corroborated in OSGeo4W shell with **ogrinfo --formats** command). So, you need a data converter for DLG vector files. This coverter can be downloaded from here: https://esri.box.com/v/sdtsdlg2shp .

At following image, you can observe its GUI.

[image]

Into unziped folder, there is User’s Manual for DLG2SHP.